# += operation on numpy array withing list increments other list elements. Np Arrays seem to be set up independently

Tags: python, pygame

I started writing a game of snake in python to familiarize myself with pygame. I didn't get very far however, because i encountered a problem.
It happens when i try to move the head of the snake in a given direction. I created a "Snake" class, which contains a normalized numpy array saying in which of the four directions the snakes head is moving and the snakes body as an array of segments where the last element is the snakes head. Each segment is a dictionary containing a numpy array describing its position and a pygame color describing its color. Maybe it would have been smarter to also create a "Segment" class but it works. Well except this one issue where substituting this line:

```
self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] = self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] + self.snake.direction
```

with this line:

```
self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] += self.snake.direction
```

changes the second to last segments position as well. Surrounding the above statement with:

```
print(self.snake.body[-2]["pos"])
```

shows me that the change happens in that one line. Which i don't get how it can have an effect on other indices.
Here is how the segment positions should develop when a 6-segment-snake just goes to the right:

```
0 [1 0]
1 [2 0]
2 [3 0]
3 [4 0]
4 [5 0]
5 [6 0]
0 [2 0]
1 [3 0]
2 [4 0]
3 [5 0]
4 [6 0]
5 [7 0]
0 [3 0]
1 [4 0]
2 [5 0]
3 [6 0]
4 [7 0]
5 [8 0]
```

Here is what happens when i use a += b instead of a = a + b:

```
0 [1 0]
1 [2 0]
2 [3 0]
3 [4 0]
4 [6 0]
5 [6 0]
0 [2 0]
1 [3 0]
2 [4 0]
3 [7 0]
4 [7 0]
5 [7 0]
0 [3 0]
1 [4 0]
2 [8 0]
3 [8 0]
4 [8 0]
5 [8 0]
```

I get that because of how my code moves the snake, the one wrong position will propagate down the line, but i don't get how it happens in the first place.

This is the part of the code that sets up the segments:

```
def __init__(self, length):
  self.length = length
  self.body = []
  for idx in range(length):
    self.body.append({"pos": np.array([idx, 0]), "color": pg.Color(0, 255, 0)})
```

I'm running up to date Manjaro Linux (basically Arch), python 3.7.3 and pygame 1.9.6 within pipenv version 2018.11.15.dev0.

Here is the whole code: (Ignore the stuff about timing, this is the first part of a two problem question that i was told to split up)

```
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import pygame as pg
pg.init()

debug_use_broken_addition = False
debug_print_segment_pos = False         # prints every segments position at each step to show it breaking
debug_use_pg_time_wait = True           # uses time.sleep instead if false, as per documentation both should not hog cpu, seems like they do anyway
debug_use_pg_clock_tick = False         # overrides debug_use_pg_time_wait, simplifies run function tremendously, also hogs cpu
debug_print_fps = False

def debug_weird_division(n, d):
  return n / d if d else 0

class Snake:
  def __init__(self, length):
    self.length = length
    self.body = []
    for idx in range(length):
      self.body.append({"pos": np.array([idx, 0]), "color": pg.Color(0, 255, 0)})
    self.body[-1]["color"] = pg.Color(255, 0, 0)
    self.direction = np.array([1, 0])
    self.speed = 2. # grid pixels / second

class Game:
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.size = self.width, self.height = size
    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(self.size)

    if debug_use_pg_clock_tick:
      self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
    else:
      self.prevTime = 0
      self.prevSleepDuration = 0

    self.dtAcc = 0
    self.snake = Snake(6)

  def handleEvent(self, event):
    if event.type == pg.QUIT: sys.exit()
    if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pg.K_w:
        self.snake.direction = np.array([0, -1])
      elif event.key == pg.K_a:
        self.snake.direction = np.array([-1, 0])
      elif event.key == pg.K_s:
        self.snake.direction = np.array([0, 1])
      elif event.key == pg.K_d:
        self.snake.direction = np.array([1, 0])

  def update(self, dt):         #comments this way =>
    self.dtAcc += dt
    if self.dtAcc >= 1 / self.snake.speed:                                              # only move the snake in steps that are defined by its speed \
      self.dtAcc -= 1 / self.snake.speed                                                # more accurate than setting it to 0

      for idx, segment in enumerate(self.snake.body[:-1]):                              # place each segment on the position of the segment in front of it   \
        segment["pos"] = self.snake.body[idx + 1]["pos"]                                # doing this for all except the first one, the head, and moving the  \
                                                                                        # head seperately afterwards, makes the snake behave like it should
      if debug_use_broken_addition:
        self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] += self.snake.direction                              # this doesn't work
      else:
        self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] = self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] + self.snake.direction  # this works

      if debug_print_segment_pos:
        for idx, segment in enumerate(self.snake.body):
          print(idx, segment["pos"])

  def draw(self):
    self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for segment in self.snake.body:
      pg.draw.rect(self.screen, segment["color"], (segment["pos"][0] * 12, segment["pos"][1] * 12, 10, 10))
    pg.display.flip()

  def run(self, framerate):
    while 1:
      if debug_use_pg_clock_tick:
        dt = self.clock.tick(framerate) / 1000
      else:
        self.time = time.time()                                                     # time in seconds
        dt = (self.time - self.prevTime) if self.prevTime != 0 else 0               # make exception if running for the first time 
        self.prevTime = self.time
        self.sleepDuration = max(0, self.prevSleepDuration - (dt - 1 / framerate))  # reduce previous sleep duration by difference between \
                                                                                    # actual and ideal dt to account for time spent not sleeping \
                                                                                    # sometimes overcompensates, would work better if single-frame \
                                                                                    # spikes in dt were ignored or averaged out
        self.prevSleepDuration = self.sleepDuration
        if debug_use_pg_time_wait:
          pg.time.wait(int(self.sleepDuration * 1000))
        else:
          time.sleep(self.sleepDuration)

      if debug_print_fps:
        print("fps: %s" % (debug_weird_division(1, dt)))

      for event in pg.event.get():
        game.handleEvent(event)

      game.update(dt)
      game.draw()

game = Game((600, 400))
game.run(30)
```

Comment: Your question title is not related to an `unexpected behaviour of + operator` but it's related that you need to know that you applied the operator only in one field of your matrix or your numpy array. You need to map your matrix and apply the operator you want.

Comment: This should probably be two separate questions, as the `+=` question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the `sleep` question except that they're both happening in the same program.

Comment: Sorry about that it was unexpected behavior for me. So could you please elaborate on what you mean by mapping a numpy array? I don't know much about math and stuff. Ok I'll remove the second part and post it as a separate question gimme a sec

Comment: As for the `+=` issue, I suspect that several of your segment positions are in fact references to the same numpy array. You haven't shown us anything about how those get set up, so I can't know for sure. But this would somewhat explain how you're getting multiple increments of the same values. The `x = x + y` makes a new array, while `x += y` mutates the existing one in place.

Comment: Ok i understand that. I'll add the snippet that sets up the segments to the question.

Comment: Does pygame really need to be part of the question at all? A proper [mre] is *minimal* -- it has the shortest working code that can be used to demonstrate the problem, and the real/underlying problem is about data structures, not pygame.

Comment: ...frankly, what this *looks like* is the list elements all being references to the same object, but there's so much code here that it's hard to isolate where anything happens.

Comment: Ahh. Actually, I think I *might* see how that's happening. You're assigning the next object's *identity*, not copying its value, in the loop -- this is a place where languages like Clojure that have all objects be immutable are much less prone to the whole class of problem, by making state and identity explicitly separate concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with these lines (debugging `if` and comments removed):

```
  for idx, segment in enumerate(self.snake.body[:-1]):
    segment["pos"] = self.snake.body[idx + 1]["pos"]              

  self.snake.body[-1]["pos"] += self.snake.direction
```

The problem here is that you're copying references to your existing position arrays from one segment of the snake's body to the next one. And importantly, after the first iteration, the second segment's position (`self.snake.body[-2]["pos"]`) is going to be a reference to the head segment's position.

When you later update the head segment's position with your `+=` code, that modification happens in place. You don't end up with a new array for the head, the way you did with the code using `+` instead of `+=`. Thus you see the modification in each of the segments that have received a reference to that same array (which is one more segment after each update).

You can make a much simpler example to see this kind of problem more clearly:

```
head_pos = [0]      # create a mutable object

body_pos = head_pos # make another reference to the same object

print(body_pos)     # prints [0]
head_pos.append(1)  # modify the list in place
print(body_pos)     # prints [0, 1], even though we haven't changed body_pos directly
```

Comment: Thank you so much for making the effort despite me posing the question in a confusing way and not providing a minimal reproducible example! I'll try to get better at stackoverflow. Learnt something new today.

Comment: @alexm: No worries, we all need to start learning somewhere. It's good to see your willingness to adapt your question to our expectations. Welcome to Stack Overflow!